# How do I validate n number of <p> tags at runtime?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I have list of `<p>` tags under a `<div>` tag and want to validate it all for any changes. The html code is for reference below.

A few of the `<p>` tags have sub tags and few do not. How do I validate all the `<p>` tags with their content to an expected value using webdriver?

```html
<div class="content content_login">
<img id="ctl00_MainContent_imgBanner" class="banner" src="../App_Themes/bsi/images/logo/banner_bsi.jpg" style="border-width:0px;">
            
<p><span id="ctl00_MainContent_lblPageContent"></span></p>
<p><strong>Important Notes: </strong>    Welcome to MyLoanWeb.com! If this is your first time visiting our new site, please 
<a href="AccountVerification.aspx">enroll for account access.</a> Accounts from loanlink.bsifinancial.com will not be valid unless they are re-enrolled.    </p> 
<p><strong>If you are experiencing any trouble receiving our emails or clicking on any of the links in the emails, please review our 
<a href="Help.aspx#Email">troubleshooting email issues</a> guide:</strong></p>
<p><strong>Please contact us if you have any questions about our services:</strong></p>

<p>ABC FinCorp Services</p>
<p>P.O. Box 456789</p> 
<p>Testville, PA</p>
<p>Customer Care Phone: 800-327-7861 </p> 
<p style="padding-bottom:0px;">Customer Care Fax: 814-217-1366</p>

</div>
```

Comment: why not simply us an HTML validator in the first pace? http://www.htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/offline/index.html.en / http://www.bjoernsworld.de/html/validator-offline.html

Comment: Thats because I have to automate the application under test and need to do it with Webdriver.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention what language you're using, so here's how I would try to do what you're doing in Java:

```
WebElement parent = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.content.content_login");
List<WebElement> paragraphs = parent.findElements(By.tagName("p"));
```

As for validating the content of the paragraphs, you'd have to extract the visible text from each of the paragraphs list items and then verify them.

Now, all this assumes that the paragraphs are all child elements of the div and that you're not going to run into any wait issues. You may have to tweak this a bit.

See: 
[When and how I can locate element by Tagname using selenium webdriver? Please explain with an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115825/when-and-how-i-can-locate-element-by-tagname-using-selenium-webdriver-please-ex)